# Laravel queue worker with supervisor

Tags: laravel, redis, queue

I have script, which executes about 5-8 mins and in the end it gives me xls file, on localhost it works fine, but on server it executes 3 times, i cannot understand why.
There is supervisor with 8 processes of queue workers.

queue connection set to redis.
laravel 5.7
Maybe someone had same problem and solved it?

.env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
```

queue

```
'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],
```

upd: 
changing retry_after => 900 doesn't help
worker starts with this command:
`artisan queue:work redis --timeout=900 --sleep=3 --tries=3`

Comment: queue config for the queue it is running on :)

Comment: Have you checked your `jobs` table? Can you find 3 rows? If yes, then the problem is the amount of dispatched jobs. If not we need to see your schedule code. And you should check your `failed_jobs` table as well.

Comment: @AndrewLarsen, it works with redis, there is no jobs or failed jobs tables. The job starts on demand from react, works about 5-8 min, this is the only thing, that use jobs in project. Jobs works correct, problem is that they work 3 times instead 1